# how to parse throgh the file system in python using <tab> key?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want is to ask the user to enter the path, but not to force him to write it completely by hand, helping him with the terminal-completion by pressing TAB? how to code it in python?

```
                 if __name__== '__main__' : 

                       path=sys.argv[1]
                  a=glob.glob(path+"/abc*")
```

here im getting path through command line. it is not hte way i want. i want to show a prompt asking user to

output expected :"enter the path of the file": 
now he should be able to parse using through file system.

note:
i dont want to take it as a command line arguments*

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2008/11/pymotw-readline.html

Comment: What have you tried? Did you even try to [google](http://google.com/search?q=Python+filesystem+api)?

Comment: can you do any favour now? @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 0):

Something like the [readline module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html) should help.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will give you a kickstart into doing what you want, it's very rough and would need to be improved for all those edge cases but hopefully you'll find it of some use. 
I just hope I've answered the question I think you were asking.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import readline
import os.path
import glob

class Completer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.matches = []
    def complete_path(self, text, state):
        if state == 0:
            self.matches = glob.glob(text + "*")
        if state < len(self.matches):
            if os.path.isdir(self.matches[state]):
                return self.matches[state] + "/"
            else:
                return self.matches[state]
        else:
            self.matches = []
            return None

readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
readline.parse_and_bind('set editing-mode emacs')

# Allow '/'
default_delims = readline.get_completer_delims()
delims = default_delims.translate(None, "/")
readline.set_completer_delims(delims)

readline.set_completer(Completer().complete_path)

while True:
    line = raw_input('Enter Path: ["^C" to quit] : ')
    print 'Line: "%s"' % line
```